# Spatialytics - failed to load resources (map)

Tags: openlayers, geospatial, spatial, mondrian, geokettle

I am working with geokettle, geomondrian and spatialytics to show the results in map.
When I reload the page of spatialytics (it is on server tomcat), the map doesn't appear(gets pink). I inspected element and I saw what is in image below:

[Click to see the image](http://www.schoolprojects.biz/failed_to_load_resources.JPG)

Anyone knows what can i do?

Cumps.

Comment: Pink tiles mean that the WMS is not served correctly, post your code to see if you have some problems there though.

Comment: was thinking about using geomondrian and friends. what has been your experience with it?

Comment: you can plot geomondrian spatial data on a map ?