# Plot Geomondrian Spatial data on a map

Tags: openlayers, pentaho, geospatial, mondrian, geokettle

Is there a way to plot and visualize **geomondrian** spatial data on map ?

i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374197/spatialytics-failed-to-load-resources-map) an issue about it ?!

i have also find an [article](https://timreview.ca/article/289) speaking about a solution (**SOLAPLAYERS**) but i didn't find a way to downloaded it from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/spatialytics/).